# Get selected category list array from category tax custom fields for sidebar menu

Tags: wordpress, acfpro

I am developing a custom theme. I needed a custom menu on the category listing page (archive.php). I need to list selected categories in this menu. I added taxonomy field with ACF. This is multi-selectable. But I can't list them in archive.php.
(No subcategories will be used)

The schema is as follows:

Category : "News"
Categories to be displayed in the sidebar content when viewing the news page: "Sports", "Politics" etc.

Category: "Announcements"
Categories to be displayed in the sidebar content when viewing the Announcements page: "Politics", "What's New", "Innovation" etc.

While editing each category, the editor will be able to select the categories to be listed in that category's sidebar. I did this with ACF. But I can't list it in archive.php.

Example query:

```
<?php $categories = get_field('categories_in_category', $taxonomy->term_id); var_dump($categories); ?>
```

This code returns null.

I tried many methods but they all return null.

**UPDATE (SOLUTION)**

For this to work, you need to prefix the parameter with "category_".
example usage:

```
<?php
$parameter_for_taxonomy_query = 'category_'.$taxonomy->term_id;
get_field('field_name', $parameter_for_taxonomy_query);
// $taxonomy is main query object from archive.php or others...
?>
```

Thanks to @tyzia

Comment: get_field() method expects post ID as second argument, but you provide term_id of $taxonomy (What do you have in your $taxonomy variable? ). See doc: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
$value = get_field( 'categories_in_category', $term_id );
```

Here you get term id of a taxonomy and get your ACF field for this term_id.

More on the topic: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/

Comment: Thank you for your interest.
I tried this, but no results.

Comment: What do you get if `var_dump($taxonomy->term_id)`?

Comment: term_id value is return correct from tax main query object. i validated this from database. if i showing "news" category, returns this category id in this page. validated from body classname, database etc.

Comment: Take any existing category ID, for example, 3 (you can see category id in url - https://njengah.com/find-category-id-wordpress/) And try this `var_dump(get_field('name', 'category_3))`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. So the "category_" prefix should be used when sending the ID parameter.

It was hard to guess that he needed it. This is not written in the ACF documentation. Where did you find this?

Comment: Happy that it helped you. It is actually in the doc: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/ See section 'Get a value from different objects' and examples.

Comment: Yes this helped me. Thanks again.
I've already looked at the link you mentioned. The truth is that; An example like 'cateogry_' is not written there. You understood this with your own interpretation. And this is your success. Thanks again for this.